# Animation Rendering Particles

Tags: rendering, animation, particles, export

I am relatively new to blender and am trying to make a small animation using the particles. The particles are visible in the viewport but when I go to render animation they are not there anymore. I am showing the emitter and followed other various tutorials but nothing is seeming to do the trick. Any support is phenomenal! Here is the link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ajRM1SVqTV0NvAygpxruCg1wGtUD6pW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome, I suggest going to the particle system, and changing the "Render > Render as" to a object, and set it to an object.

Comment: When I change it to object then the particles won't show in the animation or the viewport anymore. Is there anything else I may have to do?

Comment: nevermind, making a particle object solved my problem